# localhost:3000 not working in browser (Rails 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, localhost, port, ruby-on-rails-7

i typed `rails s` in the terminal and everything was working fine,

as my rails server was running i by mistakely pressed ctrl+z on the keyboard and next time when i tried to run `rails s` , my terminal was showing an error

`A server is already running. Check /home/..name/rprojects/railsapp/tmp/pids/server.pid.`

so i checked other solutions on stackoverflow itself and i found out we need to delete the `server.pid.` file present inside it.

after when i deleted the `server.pid.` file and typed `rails s` to start the server in the terminal, my browser keeps on loading the http://localhost:3000/ and does not render anything, it just keeps on loading and nothing happens

so then i typed `rails s -p 3001` in the terminal and it started working fine and everything is working normally on 3001 port

So how do i fix the loading problem on 3000 port when i run `rails s` in terminal and infinite loop of loading occurs and nothing happens??

even if i did not start the rails server in terminal and went on browser and typed http://localhost:3000/ , it keeps on loading and nothing shows

Answer (score 0):

You must kill the process by the `PID` which is in `server.pid`

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

ex: the PID is `1000`

```
sudo kill -9 1000
```

because you started another `rails s`, the `PID` was replaced.

You can run this cmd to find the `PID` of `rails s`

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

Comment: its showing me kill: (PID): No such process

Comment: it started working on 3000 port though, i don't know if it works by the kill process or maybe because i restarted my laptop

Comment: what did you run to kill the process?

Comment: sudo kill -9 608

Comment: it started working now

Comment: yes, next time pls kill the process stead of restarting your laptop

Answer (score 0):

I offen use this command line

1. `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)` ( 3000 is port)
2. Enter password
3. restart server